# ANTLR- syntax error(100)

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, antlr

I am a starter for ANTLR, i try to learn some examples but i could not fix this error.

```
grammar Antlr;
options{
        language = Java;
        }
@header {
        package null;
        }
@lexer::header {
        package null;
        }
rule: IDENT+;
IDENT : 'a'..'z'+;
WS : ' '+ ($channel = HIDDEN );
```

And the error message is :

> error(100): /ANTLR/src/java/com/antlr/XL.g:15:12: syntax error: antlr: unexpected token: $
>    |---> WS : ' '+ ($channel = HIDDEN;);
>
> error(10):  internal error: /ANTLR/src/java/com/antlr/XL.g : java.lang.NullPointerException
>   org.antlr.grammar.v2.ANTLRParser.ebnf(ANTLRParser.java:2742)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
WS : ' '+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

instead of:

```
WS : ' '+ ($channel = HIDDEN );
```